# Water pressure problems

Tags: water-pressure

I was going to remove a tub so I turned off what looked like in my basement, but that one just seems to spin and spin and spin. The hot water valve closed and 2 other secondary from that main looking line I closed ( water to the damn tub never stopped.... but every other water faucet shower and toilet in house stopped...) So anyways I went to open everything back up and now have very little pressure if 1 faucet is on. And weaker as I turn others on (hot or cold) it's on a pump and drainfield system the 1 faucet for sure I can't get any stronger is the kitchen sink... That's weak.. peroiod...

Answer (score 1):

It probably just dislodged some rust and build-up from the inside of the pipes, especially if they are older.

Clean out the aerators on the faucets. These are the filters that screw on at the tip of the faucet. Normally just take them apart and rinse them out, make sure not to wash any important pieces down the drain.

Comment: If the aerators are not plugged the valve that was just spinning may have not pulled the gate all the way open or another valve but something is wrong with the spinning one So I would focus there to me this sounds more probable because with 1 faucet open the others are weaker. Pointing to a supply line restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just randomly irritated twisting the main valve 30 more times.... And it found the end and everything works again.... very irritated.. I ended up turning that valve upwards of a hundred or so times to close and out was just spinning... I now know what to look out for in the future with those possibilities as well thank you guys!

Comment: If it's easy enough to do, replace it with a ball valve.